# Javascript Thumbnail Changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, thumbnails

im currently in the process of making a site and have run into a bit of a problem.  The section in question involves 3 pictures, 2 small ones and one large one.  ive got a javascript function so that when you click one of the little pictures, it takes the spot of the big one.  The issue? theres 3 sections of this in total and when you click a small picture, all of the big pictures are swapped out instead of just hte one in the appropriate section.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Heres some code.  thanks!

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('img').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('src');
        var bigUrl = $('.large-picture > img').attr('src');
        $('.large-picture > img').attr('src', url);
        $(this).attr('src', bigUrl);
        });
        });

<div class = 'picture-container'>
            <div class = 'large-picture' style = 'width:50%;height:100%;float:left;'>
                <img src = 'make-up_artist_dupontstudios.png' width = '100%' height = '100%'>
            </div>
            <div class = 'picture-content' style = 'float:right;width:45%;height:100%;'>
                <div class='picture-title'>UNIQUE CLIENT EXPERIENCE</div>
                <div class='picture-text'>Not only is our production facility unique in how easy it is to access for our clients, but our approach is always to instill a sense of comfort and relaxation for our clients. We have the options of full hair and make-up and car services available, at no additional charge, for all of our filmings.</div>
                <div class = 'small-picture-wrapper'>
                    <div class = 'small-picture' style = 'float:left;height:100%;'>
                        <img src = 'hair_and_makeup_dupontstudios.png' width = '100%' height = '100%'>
                    </div>
                    <div class = 'small-picture' style = 'float:right;height:100%;'>
                        <img src = 'infinity_wall_dupontstudios.png' width = '100%' height = '100%'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your JS to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('src');
        var bigUrl = $(this).parents('.picture-container').find('.large-picture > img').attr('src');
        $(this).parents('.picture-container').find('.large-picture > img').attr('src', url);
        $(this).attr('src', bigUrl);
    });
});
```

`$(this).parents('.picture-container')` finds the .picture-container the images are contained in, the find after it then only searches for the big image inside this container, so it does not find the other big images contained in other .picture-containers.

Comment: i gave that a shot and its still doing the same thing : /